# Convert context.request to class type

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a webservice which needs to be consumed in iphone.

```
public void test()
    {

        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new BAL_ShowOrders().test(Context.Request["obj"])));

 }
```

**The problem is that Context.Request["obj"] needs to be of Prop_ShowOrders[] type . How do i convert context.request to prop_showorders[] obj type**

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `Context.Request["obj"]` is already a `Prop_ShowOrders[]` at execution time, you could use a simple cast:

```
var orders = (Prop_ShowOrders[]) Context.Request["obj"];
var bal = new BAL_ShowOrders();
var results = bal.test(orders);
var serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(results);
Context.Response.Write(serialized);
```

Comment: I already tried casting but it says Cannot convert type 'string' to 'XXXX.Properties.Prop_ShowOrders[]'  . This is for the first line